# English Expression to Prolog

Tags: prolog

Let say I have a English expression that says:

> Day is before 8pm and after 8am

If I wanted to express this in prolog I can do something like this:

```
day(X) :- X<=2000,X>=800.    

2000 = 8pm
800 = 8am
```

But this wont work. Is there a better way to express the above English expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly smaller-equal operator in Prolog is `=<` and not `<=`. Also the above code doesn't work because operator `=` is already used. If what you are trying to achieve is to bound 8pm with value 2000 etc a simple way would be to make facts of the form:

```
fact(2000, 8-pm).
fact(800, 8-am).
```

and use it like:

```
day(X) :- fact(Y,8-pm),fact(Z,8-am),X=<Y,X>=Z.
```

Example:

```
?- day(500).
false.

?- day(900).
true ;
false.
```

Note that the above does not work with queries like `day(X)` expecting to answer the upper and lower bound of X.

Comment: would I do the same thing for night time? Let say I want to say night is after 9pm but before 4am

Comment: Yes, of course but you should match 9pm and 4am with numbers as well...note that if you match 9pm with number N1, 4am with N2 then [N1,N2] and [800,2000] shouldn't overlap in order to distinct day and night.